# How can I convert this For Loop Array into a While Loop on C Program?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

How can I convert this For Loop Array into a While Loop on C Program

```
for ( i = -20; i < 80; i = i+5 )

{

if ( i % 5 == 0 )

printf("\n");

n -= array[i];

printf("%d ", n);

}
```

Comment: seems like you answered your own question

Comment: `for (a; b; c) { d; }` is the same as `a; while (b) { d; c; }`

Comment: @amateurprogrammer What does this expression array[i] mean for i equal to -20?

Comment: Please explain what you expect that loop to do, and why you think it would work better as a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a for loop is just a fancy while loop.

```
for (x; y; z) {
   ...
}
```

is roughly equivalent<sup>[1]</sup> to

```
x;
while (y) {
   ...
   z;
}
```

There's no real point to doing this here; it just makes the code messier.

---

1. The scoping of variables declared in `x` is different. It also differs if `continue` is used.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i=-20;       //initiate
while(i<80)      //check condition
{
    if ( i % 5 == 0 )
    printf("\n");
    n -= array[i];
    printf("%d ", n);
    i=i+5;      //increment or decrement
}
```

Comment: After the code presented in this answer, will there be an identifier `i` visible? How about after the `for`-loop? (For no bonus worth a mention, add conditions about `array` such that `array[-20]` is *not* undefined behaviour.)